# as use fs.createReadStream with a path external to my project directory

Tags: node.js, electron, google-drive-api

I’m new programming, I am using createReadStream to upload an image that selects a user to google driver however createReadStream has as a base path the directory where my project is hosted while the image is hosted in any directory of the user’s pc, the application is desktop, I’m using node.js and electron googleapis.

error that shows me
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\AppEscritorio\salud{'

[error that shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKEnJ.png)

my code is

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const path = require('path');

const KEYJSON = process.env.KEYFILEGOOGLE

const SCOPE = process.env.SCOPEGOOGLE

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: KEYJSON,
    scopes: SCOPE,
})


const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth
})

const fileMetaData ={
    name: 'prueba.png',
   // parent:['1WONK0L9hDlNTfWKEYV1eyZXiXIw-yXAE'],
    mimeType: 'image/png'
}

console.log(__dirname)
const media ={
    mimeType: 'image/png',
    body: fs.createReadStream('D:/Users/RJHR/OneDrive/Imágenes/rafael.png')
}

async function saveImg() {
    try {
        const res = await drive.files.create({

            resource: fileMetaData,
            media,
            fields:'id'        
          })
          console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    
  }
  
module.exports = {saveImg}
```

Comment: What is the google.js file that is the source of the error in your error message?  Is it your file?  If so, please provide the code around the lines in that file that it refers to.  If it's not your file, can you give us a reference to the module on github where that file is?  It would help to see that file.

Comment: I appreciate your help, it was indeed a mistake in declaring a variable environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your code what part of the code would be trying to access `D:\AppEscritorio\salud{`.  The `{` is presumably wrong in that path and it appears that `D:\AppEscritorio\salud` is probably a directory too, not a file path.

This line of code:

```
body: fs.createReadStream('D:/Users/RJHR/OneDrive/Imágenes/rafael.png')
```

Looks just fine as long as that file exists.  A readable stream is permitted in the `body` property.  And, that path is not the path that shows in the error message.

So, looking through  the rest of your  code, it seems possible that one of these parameters:

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: KEYJSON,
    scopes: SCOPE,
})
```

is wrong.  Since `keyFile` is supposed to be a filename, and you're getting an error about a bad filename, I'd add a `console.log(KEYJSON)` and see what exactly it is and whether it is correct or not.  Also, if it's not a full pathname, then perhaps you also should build it into a full pathname so it's not dependent upon the current working directory.

Comment: I appreciate your help, it was indeed a mistake in declaring a variable environment